# Group by with case when don't work in mysql 5.6 strict sql mode

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a problem on a query running on our MySql server.
Here's the query:

```
SELECT itms.Gender,itms.Age, (CASE WHEN (plv.Discount = 0 OR t1.EverGreen = 1) THEN 'A' ELSE 'S' END) as SCode, itms.SubLineID, min(t1.DayDelivery)
FROM item as t1 
INNER JOIN item_contest_summary as itms 
    on (t1.SeasonID=itms.SeasonID and t1.CollectionID=itms.CollectionID and t1.ItemID=itms.ItemID and itms.JoinType<2) 
INNER JOIN pricelist_summary as plc 
    on (plc.CountryID = 'IT' AND plc.SeasonID = itms.PriceSeasonID AND plc.CollectionID = itms.PriceCollectionID AND plc.ItemID = itms.PriceItemID ) 
INNER JOIN pricelist AS plv 
    on (plv.ListCode = plc.ListCode AND plv.SeasonID = itms.PriceSeasonID AND plv.CollectionID = itms.PriceCollectionID AND plv.ItemID = itms.PriceItemID AND (plv.ListPrice > 0 or itms.IsGAG))    
WHERE itms.SCode IN ('S', 'A') AND itms.Age in ('A','K','') AND t1.HasPrivateSale = 0 AND itms.ExclLista = 0 AND itms.IsGAG = 0 
GROUP BY itms.Gender,itms.Age, 
(CASE WHEN (plv.Discount = 0 OR t1.EverGreen = 1) THEN 'A' ELSE 'S' END), 
itms.SubLineID
```

The statement used to work fine when we had strict sql disabled on server (in version 5.1), then we upgraded our systems to 5.6, enabling strict sql mode, and here problem comes.
The problem with this query seems to be the expression in the case when part:

```
(plv.Discount = 0 OR t1.EverGreen = 1)
```

Using just one of the two expressions in OR, everything works fine (both leaving the first and the second expression).
It seems that is not possibile to use any AND/OR/etc inside the expression used by case when clause. Why?
Is there any other way to write this kind of query?

### Edited:

this is the error I get in response:

> Error Code: 1055. 'plv.Discount' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: I cleaned up the real query (the is pretty longer) and cut the aggregation function. I added one in the select now, but stil not working :(

Comment: The query in the post is enough to recreate the problem: now that I added the aggregation function. Adding more join, doesn't help, since the problem is present in this simpler query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that grouping using the alias, works pretty well.
Thus the working query is:

```
SELECT itms.Gender,itms.Age, 
    (CASE WHEN (plv.Discount = 0 OR t1.EverGreen = 1) THEN 'A' ELSE 'S' END) as SCode, 
    itms.SubLineID , min(t1.DayDelivery)
FROM item as t1 
INNER JOIN item_contest_summary as itms 
    on (t1.SeasonID=itms.SeasonID and t1.CollectionID=itms.CollectionID and t1.ItemID=itms.ItemID and itms.JoinType<2) 
INNER JOIN pricelist_summary as plc 
    on (plc.CountryID = 'IT' AND plc.SeasonID = itms.PriceSeasonID AND plc.CollectionID = itms.PriceCollectionID AND plc.ItemID = itms.PriceItemID ) 
INNER JOIN pricelist AS plv 
    on (plv.ListCode = plc.ListCode AND plv.SeasonID = itms.PriceSeasonID AND plv.CollectionID = itms.PriceCollectionID AND plv.ItemID = itms.PriceItemID AND (plv.ListPrice > 0 or itms.IsGAG))    
WHERE itms.SCode IN ('S', 'A') AND itms.Age in ('A','K','') AND t1.HasPrivateSale = 0 AND itms.ExclLista = 0 AND itms.IsGAG = 0 
GROUP BY itms.Gender,itms.Age, 
    SCode, 
    itms.SubLineID
```

I still don't understand why this is needed only when using complex expression in *case when* statement.
Moreover, this version of the query works even without the aggregation function on the *select*.
Solved the problem, but still confused...